# Param not being passed to controller

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am trying to update a checkbox field on a custom object when a checkbox is checked in a list of these objects. The error is saying that no rows have been returned by my query. I am getting the object based on the ID or Name of the record clicked. My problem is I don't know which to use. I have the Name field set as an autonumber.

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!allNotes}" var="note" id="list">
            <apex:column value="{!note.Created__c}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!note.Body__c}"/>
            <apex:column> 
                <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!note.DidyaGetterDone__c}">
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" reRender="list" action="{!checkNote}">
                        <apex:param assignTo="{!noteIdValue}" value="{!note.Name}"/>
                    </apex:actionSupport>
                </apex:inputCheckbox> 
            </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Controller:

```
public with sharing class StudyPageController {

public Notes__c note{get;set;}
public List<Notes__c> allNotes{get;set;}
public String noteIdValue{get;set;}

public StudyPageController(){
    questionList = [Select id,body__c,answer__c,Name,Type__c,Explanation__c,Category__c,A__c,B__c,C__c,D__c,E__c,pic1__c,pic2__c,pic3__c,pic4__c,pic5__c From Question__c]; 
    allNotes = [Select Name,Created__c,body__c,DidyaGetterDone__c From Notes__c];
    note = new Notes__c();
}

 public void checkNote(){
  Notes__c updateNote = [Select ID,Name,DidyaGetterDone__c From Notes__c Where Name = :noteIdValue];
  updateNote.DidyaGetterDone__c = !updateNote.DidyaGetterDone__c;
  update updateNote;
  }
}
```

This is the error:

> List has no rows for assignment to SObject Error is in expression
>   '{!checkNote}' in page notespage: Class.StudyPageController.checkNote:
>   line 67, column 1

Comment: you should prefer the id, best practice.. if it does not work with Id either, your param seems not to get passed to your controller.

Comment: When param gets passed it is passed as a key value pair, as far as i know you may have to put in a name attribute where name="noteIdValue". Give it a try by adding name to the apex:param and see if the value is passed to the controller

Comment: Good catch, both of you. I added the name attribute and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@madmax 
You have note as variable which is used as in apex:pageBlockTable and you also have the same variable name defined variable in controller. Please use different names. VF is considering the controller variable which has no value in name.